# Get the matching results between two joining tables

Tags: mysql, join, inner-join, right-join

I have an `Enterprise` model :

```
name - VARCHAR 255
```

A `Candidat` model :

```
first_name - VARCHAR 255
last_name - VARCHAR 255
```

And a `Type` model :

```
name - VARCHAR 255
```

Each enterprise can select one or more types that they are interested in. Each candidat can do that as well.

I'm trying to display a list of all the candidats that share some types with the currently logged in enterprise. **They don't need to have the exact same types, just share some of them**.

I'm using two *joining tables* to keep the links between a candidat and a type, and an enterprise and a type.

```
id - INT
candidat_id - INT
type_id - INT

id - INT
enterprise_id INT
type_id INT
```

Here's the SQL query I'm using at the moment :

```
SELECT candidats.* FROM candidats
    INNER JOIN candidats_types ON candidats_types.candidat_id = candidats.id
    RIGHT JOIN entreprises_types ON entreprises_types.type_id = candidats.type_id
    WHERE entreprises_types.entreprise_id = 1
```

The **1** at the end of the query is the ID of the currently logged in enterprise, hard-coded for testing purposes.

However, this does not work, it returns an empty array, even though there are some candidates that share the same types as this enterprise.

What am I doing wrong with this query?

Answer (score 0):

According to the description of your tables, your query should generate an error, because `candidate.type_id` doesn't exist.  I would suggest:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM candidats c INNER JOIN
     candidats_types ct
     ON ct.candidat_id = c.id INNER JOIN
     entreprises_types et
     ON et.type_id = ct.type_id
WHERE et.entreprise_id = 1;
```

From the description of your problem, `RIGHT JOIN` is not necessary.